# JSP - File uploading, setting classpath and which JAR should be used in Linux?

Tags: java, linux, jsp, classpath

I am learning jsp in linux platform.I am learning in a sequential way and I am in a topic about file uploading.Here I have known that I have to set my class path and need including one or two extra JAR file in class path.I am using neither netbeans nor another IDE.

Now, please help me so that I can solve my problem about file uploading.I am confused about exact class path.

Thank you.

Comment: Please edit the question to include the source code with which you are having difficulty. Please include any error messages. Please describe how it is failing and the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

to get know tomcat path you can use `echo $CATALINA_HOME` or if tomcat is runing up then you can use `ps -ef | grep tomcat` to know path of tomcat. move your class file to  webapp folder in tomcat and move jar file to bin folder of java. you can file java path using `echo $JAVA_HOME` or `ps -ef | grep java`.